# Special services for different types of models in OOP

Tags: oop, design-patterns

This question is language-agnostic for OOP languages.

I have two classes: `DeviceA` and `DeviceB`, which inherit from model class `Device`.
I need to implement two services `DeviceAService` and `DeviceBService`, which inherit from `DeviceService`.
My language does not support generics and I need to implement methods with a `Device` parameter in `DeviceService`, that will be overridden in `DeviceAService` and `DeviceBService` and implemented differently according to the type of the `Device`. Then I want to call these functions from the generic `DeviceService`.

What is the best practice to design this? Is the use of `if` and check on class type non-avoidable here? Another idea to optimally realize this design?

Comment: This sounds like procedural programming rather than OOP. The data is in one class; the logic is in another. You have to pass the data structure into the procedure. OOP would combine the two and implement the logic in the same class with the data it needs. Then the logic becomes polymorphic.

Comment: You can have class DeviceA and DeviceB inherit from Device, and also from a mixin Service, or have Device inherit from (or use) Service if there is no multiple inheritance (and maybe a mixin is then called an Interface)

Comment: It is also possible for the objects to contain specialized Service objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have an abstract base class like this:

```
public abstract class DeviceService
{
    public abstract void DoSomething(Device device);
}
```

You want to implement `DeviceAService` and `DeviceBService` so that their behaviour differs based on the type of `Device`.

## Polymorphism

The most object-oriented design is to use polymorphism. Since `Device` is already polymorphic, put the behaviour that you want to differ into a polymorphic method, and call it from your service:

```
public override void DoSomething(Device device)
{
    // Perhaps do something first...
    device.DoThePolymorphicThing();
    // Perhaps do something else after...
}
```

Implement `DoThePolymorphicThing` differently in `DeviceA` and `DeviceB`.

## Open world

If you can't change the API of the `Device` base class, and you need to also support other implementations than `DeviceA` and `DeviceB`, you'll probably need to perform a run-time check in `DoSomething`:

```
public override void DoSomething(Device device)
{
    if (device is DeviceA)
        // Do something...
    else if (device is DeviceB)
        // Do something else...
    else
        // remember to handle the case where it's neither A nor B
}
```

We can call this type of scenario an 'open world', because `Device` is open for extensibility.

## Closed world

If, on the other hand, you know that you'll *only* ever going to have `DeviceA` and `DeviceB`, the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) design pattern is just what you need:

```
public interface IDeviceVisitor
{
    void VisitA(DeviceA device);
    void VisitB(DeviceB device);
}

public abstract class Device
{
    public abstract void Accept(IDeviceVisitor visitor);
    // Other members go here if you need them...
}

public class DeviceA : Device
{
    public override void Accept(IDeviceVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitA(this);
    }

    // Other overrides, if needed, go here...
}

// Define DeviceB in the same way...
```

You can now implement the service like this:

```
public override void DoSomething(Device device)
{
    // Perhaps do something first...
    device.Accept(new MyDeviceVisitor());
    // Perhaps do something else after...
}
```

You can think of this scenario as the 'closed world' scenario, because you can't add a third type of device without changing the Visitor API (and thus breaking existing implementations).

Comment: I find your approach very interesting. However, I would rather keep my Device classes as plain models and not implement any business logic methods in them. I'd rather implement my methods in the services. Nevertheless, your input is very useful, and a viable approach.